# negligibility of the increments of the efficient price process with respect to the first differences of the noise sequence

Tags: market-microstructure, tick-data

In high-frequency data the price process Y is contaminated by noise . We do not observe $X_t$ but the process $Y_t = X_t +u_t$ where $X_t$ is the efficient price process and $u_t$ is the microstructure noise

In the paper of  [Kolokov et al 2022](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=4184342) *Testing for Endogeneity of Irregular Sampling Schemes* to test dependence between the microstructure noise (which is not directly observed ) and the sampling times the authors states when assumption $\varepsilon_2$ is verified (section 4, page 11) the increments of the efficient price process, that is $\Delta_i^n X$ are neglegible with respect to the variation in the noise sequence.
Can someone clarify this hypothesis and how to verify this hypothesis in real data?

Comment: It is a theoretical construct that allows for the abs. exp. of the first-diff of $X_i$ and the higher moments of the abs. diff. of $X_i$, to be bounded above. This implies that while $X_i$ might have an impact on the estimate of the noisy process $Y_i$ for some $i$, the impact will on average be negligible, as the noise process will dominate the variation within $Y_i$. On real data, it still depends on the assumptions you are making, eg. is $X$ a semi-martingale ind. of the time-difference? If I were you, I would focus more on the results of the paper and worry about the assumptions later.